# Is LINQ Query Syntax Related to T-SQL Order of Execution?

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql

Does the LINQ syntax match the T-SQL order of execution? I suspect it does and thus the reason for the change in query order between SQL and LINQ but wanted some proof.

Comment: Is the order the same? I suspect yes, thus the order is different. WTF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason queries are written in the form (from i in dc.table where .... select i) is for intellisense. It has to know what you're working with before it can give you any good intellisense.

Similar to this question I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509106/why-didn't-the-linq-designers-stick-with-using-the-way-sql-is-written-today